# Parsing Exception - org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I'm running the below sql but getting a error,

> "mismatched input 'r' expecting (line 1, pos 17)" scala>
>   hiveContext.sql("select case when r.code in ‘0000’ then ‘ABC’ else
>   ‘XYZ’ end from test.reporting r left join test.exclude i on r.id =
>   i.id LEFT JOIN test.region c ON r.name = c.name where r.id IS NULL
>   limit 10").show

This looks to be an issue with **CASE** statement as if I remove case statement it works fine. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`In`** has to be **list/array** change `r.code in ‘0000’` to `r.code = ‘0000’` (or) `r.code in (‘0000’)`

```
hiveContext.sql("select case when r.code in (‘0000’) then ‘ABC’ else ‘XYZ’ end from test.reporting r left join test.exclude i on r.id = i.id LEFT JOIN test.region c ON r.name = c.name where r.id IS NULL limit 10").show
```